# Tensorflow LSTM network outputting the same values for whole batch

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

I'm running a RNN on tensorflow, in which my output is a very simple 2 vector array. All the RNN has to do is to choose one value to make 1 and one to make 0. However, when I run my batch through the RNN, I am appearing to get the same output for every input of the batch. For example:

If my actual output labels are:

```
[[ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]]
```

My RNN outputs:

```
[[  1.00000000e+00   7.93261263e-14]
 [  1.00000000e+00   7.93261263e-14]
 [  1.00000000e+00   7.93261263e-14]
 [  1.00000000e+00   7.93261263e-14]
 [  1.00000000e+00   7.93261263e-14]
 [  1.00000000e+00   7.93261263e-14]
 [  1.00000000e+00   7.93261263e-14]
 [  1.00000000e+00   7.93261263e-14]
 [  1.00000000e+00   7.93261263e-14]
 [  1.00000000e+00   7.93261263e-14]
 [  1.00000000e+00   7.93261263e-14]
 [  1.00000000e+00   7.93261263e-14]
 [  1.00000000e+00   7.93261263e-14]
 [  1.00000000e+00   7.93261263e-14]
 [  1.00000000e+00   7.93261263e-14]
 [  1.00000000e+00   7.93261263e-14]
 [  1.00000000e+00   7.93261263e-14]
 [  1.00000000e+00   7.93261263e-14]
 [  1.00000000e+00   7.93261263e-14]
 [  1.00000000e+00   7.93261263e-14]
 [  1.00000000e+00   7.93261263e-14]
 [  1.00000000e+00   7.93261263e-14]]
```

Which is clearly wrong. I'm feeding my RNN with a tensor of shape `[batch_size, time_steps_features]` and I'm using `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn()` to run the RNN. Nothing I have tried seems to work.

I have been ripping my hair out on this, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you might not re-shuffle the samples in your batches between epochs. This can lead the minimization (of the error) to a local minimum which you won't get out of.

Try not to provide the input in the same order in every iteration and you should converge to something more sensible.